# Program to read binary and determine filetype

Tags: c, binary, fread

I wrote this code which reads a file binary and determines its filetype (for a few test fileendings).It works fine for PDF, MP3 but not for jpg.

What is the problem? For jpg the line `printf("%s[%d]: %x\n", "Buffer", j, buffer[j]);` shows me multiple bytes (i.e ffffff instead of just one byte)

```
#include <stdio.h>


const int header[6][8] =    { 
                            {0x89,0x50,0x4E,0x47,0x0D,0x0A,0x1A,0x0A},
                            {0xFF,0xD8,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},
                            {0xFF,0xFB,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},
                            {0x49,0x44,0x33,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},
                            {0x25,0x50,0x44,0x46,0x2D,0x00,0x00,0x00},
                            {0x42,0x4C,0x45,0x4E,0x44,0x45,0x52,0x00} 
                            };

const char* filetype[6] = {"PNG","JPG","MP3","MP3v2","PDF","Blender"};

int main()
{
    FILE *fd;
    char buffer[8];


    if ((fd = fopen("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\Unnamed.jpg", "rb")) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    //fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, fd);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fd);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            printf("%s[%d][%d]: %x\n","Header",i,j,header[i][j]);
            printf("%s[%d]: %x\n", "Buffer", j, buffer[j]);

            if (header[i][j] == 0x00) {
                printf("%s: %s","Found file type",filetype[i]);
                return 1;
            }
            if (header[i][j] != buffer[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", "Couldn't determine filetype - Not in library");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better code would use the return value from `fread()` to know how many bytes were read.

Comment: Why use `char` for `char buffer[8];` and a different type `int` in `int header[6][8]` for pattern matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unsigned char` for `buffer` (you can also for `header`) to avoid problem if your `char` are signed and give a negative value (you compare with *int* like 0x89 where the bit 7 is set)

You also have a problem for PNG because the values for PNG are :

> {0x89,0x50,0x4E,0x47,0x0D,0x0A,0x1A,0x0A},

there are not ended by 0 like in all the other cases, this is needed because your algorithm need to find 0 to indicate you found :

```
        if (header[i][j] == 0x00) {
            printf("%s: %s","Found file type",filetype[i]);
            return 1;
        }
```

Just add a column to also have 0 also for PNG.

Finally :

```
const unsigned char header[6][9] =    { 
                            {0x89,0x50,0x4E,0x47,0x0D,0x0A,0x1A,0x0A, 0x00},
                            {0xFF,0xD8,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00},
                            {0xFF,0xFB,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00},
                            {0x49,0x44,0x33,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00},
                            {0x25,0x50,0x44,0x46,0x2D,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00},
                            {0x42,0x4C,0x45,0x4E,0x44,0x45,0x52,0x00, 0x00} 
                            };

const char* filetype[6] = {"PNG","JPG","MP3","MP3v2","PDF","Blender"};

int main()
{
    FILE *fd;
    unsigned char buffer[sizeof(header[0])];


    if ((fd = fopen("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\Unnamed.jpg", "rb")) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fd);

    for (int i = 0; i < ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(header[0]); j++){
            printf("%s[%d][%d]: %x\n","Header",i,j,header[i][j]);
            printf("%s[%d]: %x\n", "Buffer", j, buffer[j]);

            if (header[i][j] == 0x00) {
                printf("%s: %s","Found file type",filetype[i]);
                return 1;
            }
            if (header[i][j] != buffer[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", "Couldn't determine filetype - Not in library");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to make your buffer `unsigned char`, so you're getting sign extension on the values.

Clearly the table of built-in magic signatures should be `const unsigned char`, too, and the comparison should be made with a single `memcmp()` call.

Comment: Ah i searched for something like memcmp. Did not find this. Thank you.